# Return all text to the right of last numeric digit in strings

Tags: excel, function, substring

Return the right text string of a cell until the first number from the right e.g.

"geb. 14 oct 1956 Westerkerk HRL" must return `Westerkerk HRL`
"geb. 14 oct 1956" must return empty cell
" " must return empty cell

Comment: SO is not a code outsourcing site. If you have a precise question you can ask it provided you show effort.

Answer (score 2):

Formula solution:

`=TRIM(MID(A1,1+MAX(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1&"1234567890")*ISNUMBER(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1))),LEN(A1)))`

**EDIT**: I realized that the above formula may run into issues if there is a repeated number (for example if it had been 1966 instead of 1956), so I went back and came up with this which will not be affected by that issue:

`=TRIM(MID(A1,1+LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))),LEN(A1)))`

However, `INDIRECT` is a volatile function and I usually try to avoid it.  You could instead use a number which is going to be higher than the length of your text strings in order to accomplish the same goal without a volatile function, though this may not actually be any faster than using the `INDIRECT` function in the formula:

`=TRIM(MID(A1,1+LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW($1:$255),1)),ROW($1:$255)),LEN(A1)))`

So basically, you can use either formula, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of monkey work - someone might have a simpler solution - but first you'd need to get the highest lastIndexOf '0' through '9'. In your example, the number is '6'. From that, you can create a substring.

```
var c = 'geb. 14 oct 1956 Westerkerk HRL';  // c for companyname
var subc = '';
var startsub = c.lastIndexOf('6') + 2;      // Point past the space to the W.
if(c.length > startsub) subc = c.substring(startsub, c.length);

     return subc;
```

Comment: Just noticed the Excel tag. I gave you scripting code. pnuts is correct in the need for regex functionality.